# zip not Extracting to target directory

Tags: c#-3.0

This is the code
   using (ZipFile zipnew = ZipFile.Read(strPath))
   {
      foreach (ZipEntry zenew in zipnew)
      {  zenew.Extract(exPath); }

zenew.filename="c:\temp\images\fish2.jpg"
exPath = "c:\temp\members\12\images"

I get this error The file C:\temp\Images\fish2.jpg already exists.

Hope to get a reply
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the Overwrite flag to something.  Here is an example:

```
using (ZipFile zipnew = ZipFile.Read(strPath)) { foreach (ZipEntry zenew in zipnew)        
   {
      zenew.filename="c:\temp\images\fish2.jpg"
      exPath = "c:\temp\members\12\images"
      zenew.Extract(exPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
   }
```